# dropdown menu behind element

Tags: html, css

i have something wierd to going on with my menu

1 screen cap 1 show it works fine
2. screen cap two shows it has an issue

[image]

[image]

here is the code please help me im stuck

```
#navigation { margin-top: -17px; }
.region-nav-main .content {background:#6f0d1c; height:28px; color:#fff; width:auto; float:right; font:11px 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li {float:left; list-style:none; display:inline; position:relative; z-index:997; padding:0; margin:0;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li a {color:#fff; text-decoration:none; padding:0 10px; display:block; line-height:28px;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li a:hover {background:#242121;}


.region-nav-main .content  ul li.expanded a {background:url(../images/parent-dd.gif) right 12px no-repeat; padding:0 22px 0 10px;}
.region-nav-main .content  ul li a.parent:hover, .region-nav-main .content ul li.hover a, .region-nav-main .content ul li.hover a:hover, .region-nav-main .content  ul li.expanded a.active {background:#242121 url(../images/parent-dd.gif) right -82px no-repeat;}
.region-nav-main .content  ul li a.active {background:#242121}
.region-nav-main .content  ul li.expanded a.active-trail {background: #242121 url(../images/parent-dd.gif) right -82px no-repeat;}
.region-nav-main .content  ul li.expanded li a {background:none;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li.hover li a:hover {background:#3a3a3a none;}

.region-nav-main .content ul li ul {display:none; position:absolute; top:28px; left:0; z-index:998;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li {background:#242121; border-bottom:1px solid #383535; display:block; float:none; color:#868686; float:left; clear:both;z-index:998;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li.last {border:0 none;z-index:991;}



.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li:hover ul{ display:block;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li a {color:#868686; background:none; width:135px;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li a:hover {background:#3a3a3a; color:#fff;}

.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li ul{left:144px; top:-2px; display:none;}
```

i have tried the following with no luck

```
.region-nav-main .content ul li{z-index:990 !important;}

.region-nav-main .content ul li ul {z-index:995 !important;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li {z-index:995 !important;}

.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li ul {z-index:999 !important;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li ul li {z-index:999 !important;}
```

Comment: Try using differents `z-index` for each nested level.

Answer (score 0):

Your `z-index` at `.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li.last` is lower than your parent `.region-nav-main .content ul li` thus making it hide because of the stack order. You need to set a higher `z-index` value to `.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li.last`.

Comment: i have updated this and set all level with there own z-index and it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

As EmCo said it seems to be a z-index issue.  It looks like the nested li displaying fine has a z-index of 998 and the li.last has z-index of 991.  Perhaps changing li.last to have a z-index of 998 will fix it.

Comment: i set made each level with its own z-index but still get that same issue

Comment: With the code you have above, just change this line `.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li.last {border:0 none;z-index:991;}` to have a z-index of 998.

Comment: no this didn't work all z index show are set but i still get the same issue

Comment: Alright, well I am pretty confident the z-index on the li.last is causing this problem (that's why the first screen shot seems to appear correct and the second is 'broke' - because the first screen shot the main menu isn't long enough so the z-index is not an issue).  If you haven't already make sure you are clearing your browser cache after you make changes.  Sorry I can't be of anymore help, best of luck to you!

Comment: base on the setting up the z-index for each menu now i get the same issue on both section it no longer a last issue

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured out the solution if anyone is interested

these are the only set z-index for my menus

```
.region-nav-main .content ul li ul {z-index:985 !important;}
.region-nav-main .content ul li ul li ul {z-index:977 !important;}
```

i am completely baffled as to why this is working but it does in safari, opera, chrome and IE

Answer (score 0):

li.last does not need its own z-index value, because it will inherit it from the previous styles for that level of li. Just remove z-index from the li.last styles entirely and it should work.